Does codec of mp4 effect defining buildozer.spec file?
I'm trying to build a kivy app, it works well on my laptop. I'm using buildozer to make it into an apk but for some reason when i run it on my phone, i get white screen instead of the mp4 file.
I have multiple jpg/png files but they show up where they should, only the mp4 files dont. What might be the reason for it?
I thought of checking the codec, and the file is mp42, but it shouldn't really have an effect right?
My buildozer file (relevant lines) look like :
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,mp4
what might be the reason I'm seeing the white screen instead of video?

Android has specific codec/profile support for media: https://developer.android.com/media/platform/supported-formats Best is to try the video on an open-source video player to see if the media is supported and on device testing is better than emulator.

maybe system doesn't have (C/C++) library to display this type of video. So it can be problem with system, but  not directly with kivy, python or buildozer
